# how to get twitter secret from hello.js response

Tags: hello.js

I want to use hello JS only to get the users access token and secret so i can send them to my backend for storage, I tried placing a log like so

```
twitter.login().then( function(r){ 
    console.log('response===>', r); 
}
```

In the response I can see the access token, but there is no secret, Is there a setting I can enable to get the secret?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out i can deduce it from the way the auth_token is sent back:

```
consumer_key:consumer_secret@app_key
```